# Sending data to Activity without startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I send data to another Activity that did not `startActivityForResult`?

I `Override` the `onActivityResult` method in order to perform logic as soon as a result returns from another Activity. Specifically, from my `EditItemActivity`

Process:

Within my `MainActivity`,

[image]

when I click on an item in the `ListView`, I am redirected to another Activity called `ToDoDetailActivity`

[image]

When I click the `Edit` button I am redirector to another Activity called `EditItemActivity"`

[image]

As soon as I make my changes and press the `Edit` button on the `EditItemActivity`, I return back to the `MainActivity`

```
data = new Intent(EditItemActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
data.putExtra(EDITTEXT_VALUE, etValue);
setResult(123, data);
startActivity(data);
```

Within my MainActivity, I want to UPDATE the item I just edited with this logic within my `onActivityResult` method. However, I don't see any logs in `LogCat` meaning I do not believe this method is being used and therefore no logic is performed

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (data == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (resultCode == 123) {
            String editedItemValue = data.getStringExtra(EditItemActivity.EDITTEXT_VALUE);    
            todoItems.remove(editedPosition);
            aToDoAdapter.insert(editedItemValue, editedPosition);
            aToDoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
data = new Intent(EditItemActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
data.putExtra(EDITTEXT_VALUE, etValue);
setResult(123, data);
startActivity(data);
```

When you execute startActivity with MainActivity.class it is launching a new Activity so you are not going to find a result in "onActivityResult" method.  It is because you are not returning to the main activity after finishing in a "child" activity.

What I have done in the past is use broadcast event to notify the "MainActivity" about updating the view.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `BroadcastReceiver` or use database to store the result of your edit in `EditItemActivity` then update that result in onResume method of `MainActivity`